# Why won't this html/javascript clock work?

Tags: javascript, clock

My problem is that it logs to the console 2 times. I could not figure out what was wrong. If it were to execute the code in both the if and else parts, it would have logged both the hours + 0 + the minutes, then the normal time. It does not do that, and it only executes what it should 2 times.

```js
function GtD() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var minute = d.getMinutes();
  if (minute >= 0 && minute <= 9) {
    console.log(hour + ":" + "0" + minute);
  } else {
    console.log(hour + ":" + minute);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getElementById(GtD()), GtD()">
  Click to get the current time
</button>
```

Comment: You're calling `GtD()` twice in your `onclick`.

Answer (score 2):

#### Simply because you've called the function twice

Let's look at your HTML:

```
<button onclick="getElementById(GtD()), GtD()">
  Click to get the current time
</button>
```

More specifically

```
onclick="getElementById(GtD()), GtD()"
```

You're calling `getElementById` with `GtD()` as an argument. That will call your `GtD` function once. You then call `GtD()` after `getElementById`. So naturally there are going to be two console logs. This can simply be changed to the following

```js
function GtD() {
  var d = new Date();
  var hour = d.getHours();
  var minute = d.getMinutes();
  if (minute >= 0 && minute <= 9) {
    console.log(hour + ":" + "0" + minute);
  } else {
    console.log(hour + ":" + minute);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="GtD()">
      Click to get the current time
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

## You called it twice.

In your onclick you included `getElementByID(Gtd())` which doesn't make an sense, since your function `GtD()` doesn't return a value. You don't need to get an element by ID. You only want to log to the console.

Just leave that out:

```
<button onclick="GtD()">
     Click to get the current time
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are executing the function twice in your onclick element.

Change to `<button onclick="GtD()">`

Comment: thank you so much for all of your help. I always thought you absolutely had to get the function from the javascript before you can execute it in html.